# Ruby `debug` gem does not accept arrow keys and shows the key typing as ASCII sequences, and then frozes

Tags: debugging, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-7

I am currently using Ruby on Rails 7, PostgreSQL, MongoDB and GraphQL to develop a web application.
However, when I was trying to debug the Ruby code, `rgdb` does not take arrow keys correctly, and then frozen.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the issue was cause by `DatabaseCleaner`, and a workaround is to comment out some settings for `Databasecleaner`.

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    #DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean_with(:deletion)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    # DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :deletion
  end
  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    #DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :deletion
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    # DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
  config.before(:all) do
    # DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:all) do
    # DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```